# Inconsistent behavior when hover on inner element

Tags: html, css

Consider this code (https://codepen.io/raelb/pen/KBEaXq):

HTML:

```
<div class="container" >

<a href=hello>
  <div class=block>Notebook
    <span class=count>10</span>
  </div>
</a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

.block {
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
border: 1px silver solid;
margin-bottom: 4px;
padding: 2px;
padding-right: 4px;
padding-left: 4px;
font-size: 13px;
}

.block:hover {
background-color: gray;
color: white;
}

.count {
color: green;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 2px;
padding-left: 4px;
border-left: 1px silver solid;
}

.count:hover{
  color: white;
}
```

If `.count` does not contain the color property, then when I hover over the block, the count text will go white (automatically). However, if color is defined, then when I hover over the block, the count text is unaffected, (and also, the `.count:hover` selector is not active).

So, this seems inconsistent. In one case a hover color is applied to the inner span, however in the other case no hover color is applied.

Why is this? And is there a way to get `.count:hover` to apply to the count, when I hover over the block div and have defined a color property for `.count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the count to turn white whenever you hover over the block. This can simply be done by changing the properties of .count whenever the block element is hovered on. In your CSS, you change the color of the count whenever the count element is hovered on and the count's hover box is smaller than the box of the block. This can be fixed by implementing this code in place of your last definition in your CSS:

```
    .block:hover .count {
      color: white;
    }
```

Here's a working example.

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  border: 1px silver solid;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.block:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.count {
  color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-left: 1px silver solid;
}

.block:hover .count {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <a href=hello>
    <div class=block>Notebook
      <span class=count>10</span>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

You can also find it on Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBQJOr).

Comment: `.block:hover .count:hover` ?

Answer (score 1):

The inconsistent behavior you are referring to is totally expected based on the CSS Specificity rules.

Quoting from [here](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/):

> Specifity is not inherited. If you declare 27 values on a parent of a paragraph, and even add !important, but declare the paragraph separately, the property declared on the element will be applied. Inheritance does not trump such declarations.

That means that when hover on .block div, the rules specified for .count selector have bigger priority that rules for .block:hover selector, so the .count text remains green when hover on .block div, because the rule:

```
.count {
    color: green;
}
```

overrides the rule:

```
.block:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

That explains the fact that when you omit the color rule for .count (color: green), the color rule .block:hover is applied (color: white), but when you do have a color rule for .count then this rule is applied and the span.count remains green.

Given your css rules, you have to hover on .count for the color to become white.

TusharDevelops has already answered how to solve your practical problem I just explain the theory behind this.